# SIGSEGV segmentation fault when writing, but not reading?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a namespace `ECFS` an inline function in it, and I have the following:

```
inline void changeData(char* data, uint32_t len) {
    for (; len != 0; --len, --curpos) {
        std::cout << data[len] << std::endl;
        data[len] = 'C';
    }
}
```

The read works absolutely fine, but the write causes a segfault. I have allocated the data and made sure `len` is not out of bounds and I have no clue what's happening.

EDIT: The lines I'm using to call it are:

```
char* str = new char[13];
str = "Hello world!";
ECFS::changeData(str, 12); // SIGSEGV
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling it. I'll bet $1,000 you're passing it a pointer to a constant. (You can't modify a constant, that's what makes it constant.)

Comment: Helpful:  your use of `len` as an index is not taking into account that indexes are 0 through array size - 1.  The calling source accounts for it, but for good coding practice, it would help to show it in your naming/usage.

Comment: @donjuedo I was gonna change it to a while loop (with correct indexes :P) anyway, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* str = new char[13];
str = "Hello world!";
ECFS::changeData(str, 12); // SIGSEGV
```

You allocate 13 bytes and store a pointer to them in `str`. Then you throw that pointer away and change `str` to point to a constant. Then you try to modify what `str` points to, which is a constant. You can't modify a constant.

You wanted:

```
char* str = new char[13];
strcpy(str, "Hello world!");
ECFS::changeData(str, 12);
```

Comment: Still getting used to pointers.... just assumed that would write to the array. :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the code

```
char* str = new char[13];
str = "Hello world!";
```

> just assumed that would write to the array.

That is not what is happening here. In

```
str = "Hello world!";
```

You are making the `str` pointer pointing to read only data (commonly put as `.rodata` in assembly). Any attempt to write to read only data results in segmentation fault or `SIGSEGV`.